# The positive determinant of one special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I try to prove the positive value of determinant for matrix ($n\times n$ for any $n$):

\begin{equation*} 
||a_{ij}|| = ||f(x_i - y_j)||
, \text{where}~f = f(\lambda(x - y)) = \exp(-\lambda(x - y)^2),~\lambda > 0,\\
x_1 < ... < x_n,~y_1 < ... < y_n,~x_i \in [0; 1],~y_i \in [0; 1].
\end{equation*}

For $n=2$ this easily to show, but even for $n=3$ the explicitly calculating is cumbersome. I have an idea of proof using method of mathematical induction, but my efforts didn't bring success.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to [positive definite functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function) in some way

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, the exception is in real values of presented function, of course.

Comment: This post might be interesting : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153353/determinant-and-eigenvalues-of-a-specific-matrix (and I believe the following this paper may help you : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379592902559)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, the problem was solved, for function $exp(-(x-y)^2)$. If we take out off the determinant all the multipliers $exp(−x_i^2) > 0$ and $exp(-y_j^2) > 0$, $i,j=1,\dots,n$, we will get the generalized Vandermonde Matrix, and it is known as positive.

Answer (score 0):

Omnomnomnom is right. Gaussian function is (strictly) positive definite (Wendland's "Scattered data approximation", pp.74,76) and leads to PD matrices. The determinant of a positive definite matrix is always positive.

Comment: I see the difficulty in a) function $f$ depends on 2 variables, b) with real values and, what is most important, c) matrix $A$ is nonsymmetric. The using of theorem in abovementioned book seems inappropriate to me. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, indeed, you don't have one but two sets of pairwise distinct centers, so the results of that book don't seem to be directly applicable. Let me think for a while before I'd either update or delete this answer.